# How to check if specific lat lng locate in polygon or not using sequelize

Tags: geometry, sequelize.js, polygon

[image]

I have one table that have polygon column. I would like to check if a certain lat lng is in that polygon or not using sequelize framework.

Comment: Please specify a DBMS you are using

Comment: I am using mysql

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
ST_Contains(polygon, ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(Point(lon, lat)), 4326))
```